# Quick fix for a python import suggests workspace path instead of a package

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have a function which is missing an import statement:
[image].

`Quick Fix` proposes an import from the absolute workspace path which leads to the 'Module Not Found' error. Why doesn't it propose to import this function from a package that is installed in the environment used to run the code?

Comment: Quick Fix is just a tool to help you write code more efficiently, 
and it's not perfect and it might not always provide the correct suggestion, especially for more complex situations. In your case, you have to manually import the function from the correct package.

Comment: That's absolutely right. But my use case should be quite common which makes me wonder why the tool doesn't support it, guessing at the same time that I am misusing the tool in some way